# In what circumstances is there an unique solution to $f(x)=y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I'm working through the following video with Khan Academy which has me very confused.

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/matrix-transformations/inverse-transformations/v/proof-invertibility-implies-a-unique-solution-to-f-x-y

Sal seems to imply that the function $f(x)$ only map one x to one singular y, and that additionally, one value in our co-domain will map to one and only one value in our domain.

But this seems absurd to me. If I would specify my function as $x^2$ that would mean each number in our co-domain would map to two members in our domain, the positive and negative square root of itself. If I were to specify the function to be $x^\frac{1}{2}$ then every member of our domain would map to two members in our co-domain by the same logic.

Also, if each member in our domain only mapped to one member in our co-domain, this would imply that none of our trigonometric functions are "functions" in any real sense, since a function such as $\sin(x)$ would map a specific value in our co-domain (say 0) to an infinite set of values in our domain $(0,2\pi, 4\pi,....)$

This is pretty disturbing for me. Is this a real theorem at all and if so, when does it apply? Does it apply specifically in relation to linear transformations?

Comment: That lesson seems to specifically talk about invertible functions $f$, where that condition holds by definition

Comment: The functions defined by $x^2,x^{1/2},$ and $\sin(x)$ are not **linear transformations,** which is what Sal seems to be discussing in the video

Comment: But $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R, x\mapsto x^2$ is not invertible.

Comment: The inverse function of $f(x)=x^2$ would seem to be $fIx)=x^\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: That's true only if you restrict the domain to non negative $x$. If $x<0$ you have $f^{-1}(f(x))=-x\ne x$